# How to test SCIM endpoints

Tags: c#, basic-authentication, scim

I am currently adding SCIM compliment endpoints to one of our products (on-prem user management). These endpoints should allow Identity providers (i.e., Okta) to connect via HTTP basic Auth and provision users into our system. The problem is that I have no way to test if the endpoints work correctly. I have been looking for software to test with, but I can’t seem to find anything. How can I test that the endpoints are working properly and are SCIM compliant?

Answer (score 2):

Okta itself has published these recommendations for how to test your implementation. They have a suite of tests for Runscope that can be used.

https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/build-provisioning-integration/test-scim-server/

You can then sign up for an Okta developer account and test further with Okta actually hitting your service.